# Newer Android devices and GLES 3.2 support

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, rendering

Is it expected (or what is the likelihood) that newly produced Android devices to not have GLES 3.2 support? We're developing children apps so we're trying to see what are the odds we get new devices on the market in the future that can cause us problems...

What we need is floating point render textures in unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google publish data [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) (googling 'android distribution dashboard' will find it in case the link goes stale)

Currently, 78.61% of Google Play users are on devices that support GLES 3.2.

Going forward, I'd say it's a certainty that *some* newly produced Android won't have 3.2 support, but I think they'll be relatively rare devices and aimed at the cheaper end of the market.

Comment: Thanks, as much as we don't like it then, it might be an idea to support that part of the market too, though our products have about 95% of their users being on GLES3.2+, i was wondering if those are just old devices or also the new, cheap ones.

...but the android market is so big...